# Double string.format

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

I have some double values I want to convert to a string with this pattern:

```
0.xx or x.xx
```

Currently I have try this:

```
double.ToString("#.#0");
```

What should I add in order to see zero in case my number start with zero?

Comment: Use yourdoublevariable.ToString("N2")

Answer (score 34, accepted):

just use

```
myDouble.ToString("0.00")
```

that should do the trick

Answer (score 8):

```
myDouble.ToString("N2")
```

should also work.

Have a look at

[MSDN: Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

[MSDN: Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 111.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Put a zero in front of the decimal separator:

```
double.ToString("0.#0");
```

This will always include the digit, in contrast to `#` which makes it optional.

Answer (score 2):

use following :

```
myDouble.ToString("N2")
```